# render into alternative layout in ember 2

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When I try to render into a alternative layout from a route, I get a error saying the layout is not found. `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You attempted to render into 'popup' but it was not found`
Is it not possible to render into a alternative layout? I want to render the view but without navigation.
If I render into application it works fine

My route looks like

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.find('information', params.information_id);
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('informations/show', {
      into: 'popup'
    });
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The routes nesting will define your layout. So don`t compose routes with models in mind.

If you want your navigation only on your application route, put them in the application.index route. if it is not clear what is rendered, turn on debugging.(https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/debugging/).

PS: we call it "outlet"

Comment: I understand all this but I want to use a different template. You can define the template that is used for rendering with the `into` option if I understand the documentation correctly. What you are saying is that `application.hbs` should be empty and only have `{{outlet}}`? since it is the root of all routes and it's template will always be rendered.